# Set mongodb read preference at mongo server level

Tags: mongodb

I have one PRIMARY instance and one SECONDARY instance of mongodb.

Many clients are using my two instances. Each client has its own read preference to "secondary"
My question is :
Is there a way to configure mongodb to set by default the read preference to "secondary" ?

Thanks

MC

Answer (score 3):

Read preference is a *client* setting, not a server setting, so no, this is not possible as far as I know. An important feature of MongoDB is that you have very fine-grained control over the queries, i.e. you can use different read preferences and write concerns for each query.

It often makes sense to mix these, because losing a log entry might not be too bad while losing a payment is. Likewise, reading logs from the secondary might be fine, but if you want to coordinate a transaction, it might be safer to use the primary for reading (or you're using a paranoid write concern that requires full replication before considering the write successful).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was looking for a way to set a mongodb default behaviour for replica set and read preference but it seems i cannot do that at server side. Thanks anyway.